# Most efficient way to compute similarity on high-dimensional data

Tags: scikit-learn, data-mining, similarity, nearest-neighbor

I have a large list (>10k) of user interests. Each list is fairly long and contains some user interests, e.g. ['football', 'boxing', 'movies' ..], and varies from user to user. So the data is quite high-dimensional.

Now, I want to compute the pairwise similarity between each list. Actually, to be specific, for a certain list, I want to get the n-most similar lists, where n is arbitrary. I'm using scikit for this, and thus far, I've just been vectorizing the lists and computing the cosine similarity between each list. This, understandably, seems to be quite slow and doesn't scale well to large but sparse datasets. Would I be better served using something like a kd-Tree or a Ball-Tree?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way for **sparse** data and cosine is an inverted lists index.

Think of a text search engine. It does exactly what you need.

Comment: Either this, or a random projection onto a smaller space where kd-trees  become useful. +1.